# How to make upload faster in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, file, file-upload

I am trying to speed up the upload. So I tried with different solution, with both BackEnd and Front-End. Those are,

**1)** I uploaded the tar file (already compressed one)

**2)** I tried chunk upload (sequentially), if the response is success next API will get triggered. In the back-end side, in the same file the content will get appended.

**3)** I tried chunk upload but in parallel, at a single time I make the 50 request to upload the chunk content (I know, at a time browser handle only 6 requests). From the backend side, we are storing all the chunk file separately, after receiving the final request, appending all those chunks in to the single file.

But observed is, I am not seeing the much difference with all these cases.

Following is my service file

```
export class largeGeneUpload {

    chromosomeFile: any;
    options: any;
    chunkSize = 1200000;
    activeConnections = 0;
    threadsQuantity = 50;

    totalChunkCount = 0;
    chunksPosition = 0;
    failedChunks = [];


    sendNext() {
        if (this.activeConnections >= this.threadsQuantity) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.chunksPosition === this.totalChunkCount) {
            console.log('all chunks are done');
            return;
        }

        const i = this.chunksPosition;
        const url = 'gene/human';
        const chunkIndex = i;
        const start = chunkIndex * this.chunkSize;
        const end = Math.min(start + this.chunkSize, this.chromosomeFile.size);
        const currentchunkSize = this.chunkSize * i;
        const chunkData = this.chromosomeFile.webkitSlice ? this.chromosomeFile.webkitSlice(start, end) : this.chromosomeFile.slice(start, end);
        const fd = new FormData();
        const binar = new File([chunkData], this.chromosomeFile.upload.filename);
        console.log(binar);
        fd.append('file', binar);
        fd.append('dzuuid', this.chromosomeFile.upload.uuid);
        fd.append('dzchunkindex', chunkIndex.toString());
        fd.append('dztotalfilesize', this.chromosomeFile.upload.total);
        fd.append('dzchunksize', this.chunkSize.toString());
        fd.append('dztotalchunkcount', this.chromosomeFile.upload.totalChunkCount);
        fd.append('isCancel', 'false');
        fd.append('dzchunkbyteoffset', currentchunkSize.toString());

        this.chunksPosition += 1;
        this.activeConnections += 1;
        this.apiDataService.uploadChunk(url, fd)
            .then(() => {
                this.activeConnections -= 1;
                this.sendNext();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.activeConnections -= 1;
                console.log('error here');
                // chunksQueue.push(chunkId);
            });

        this.sendNext();
    }


    uploadChunk(resrc: string, item) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._http.post(this.baseApiUrl + resrc, item, {
                headers: this.headers,
                withCredentials: true
            }).subscribe(r => {
                console.log(r);
                resolve();
            }, err => {
                console.log('err', err);
                reject();
            });
        });
}
```

But the thing is, If I upload the same file in google drive it is not taking much time.

Let's consider, I have 700 MB file, to upload it in google drive it took 3 mins. But the same 700 MB file to upload with my Angular code with our back-end server it took 7 mins to finish it.

How do I improve the performance of file upload.?

Answer (score 0):

forgive me , 
it seems silly answer but this depend on your hosting infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

A lot of variables can cause this, but by your story it has nothing to do with your front-end code. Making it into chunks is not going to help, because browsers have their own optimized algorithm to upload files. The most likely culprit is your backend server or the connection from your client to the server.

You say that google drive is fast, but you should also know that google has a very widespread global infrastructure with top of the line cloud servers. If you are using, for example, a 2 euro per month fixed place hosting provider, you cannot expect the same processing and network power as google.